# Unable to get multiple notifications at different time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I'm trying to set a notification at specific times whenever user clicks a button.

Like this:

```
// make this duration fifteen minutes before startTime
                        long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + Long.parseLong(holder.handlerGapTV.getText().toString());
                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) holder.itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

                        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
                            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.class);
                            notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.NOTIFICATION, holder.getNotification(i));
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(holder.itemView.getContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
                            intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
                        }
```

`Long.parseLong(holder.handlerGapTV.getText().toString())` has been calculated as:

```
try {
            Date date3 = todayTimeDateFormat.parse(todayTimeDate);
            Date date4 = todayTimeDateFormat.parse(newTime);

            holder.handlerGap = date4.getTime() - date3.getTime();
            holder.handlerGapTV.setText(String.valueOf(holder.handlerGap));
            holder.handlerGapTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.d("handlerGapTV.getText()", holder.handlerGapTV.getText().toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here's `getNotification()`:

```
private Notification getNotification(int repeat) {
            mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(itemView.getContext())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon_1)
                            .setContentTitle("Notif title")
                            .setContentText("Notif text");

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), AcceptedRequest.class);
            // Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity, there's
            // no need to create an artificial back stack.
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            itemView.getContext(),
                            repeat,
                            resultIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            return mBuilder.build();
        }
```

and here's `NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.java`:

```
public class NotificationARBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        mNotifyMgr.notify(m, notification);

    }
}
```

**The problem** is that `Long.parseLong(holder.handlerGapTV.getText().toString())` is different for the `CardView` on which the button is and suppose that if it is `100` seconds for card1's button then it is `65` for card2's button and if I press card2 button first and card2 button after it, the notification is set according to the card2's timing, i.e. `100` and the card1's timing notification is never shown!

**What I want** is to show each and every notification whether it is set after `100` seconds or `65`.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, changing the code from this:

```
long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + Long.parseLong(holder.handlerGapTV.getText().toString());
                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) holder.itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

                        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
                            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.class);
                            notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.NOTIFICATION, holder.getNotification(i));
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(holder.itemView.getContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
                            intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
                        }
```

to this:

```
int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);

                        // make this duration fifteen minutes before startTime
                        long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + Long.parseLong(holder.handlerGapTV.getText().toString());
                        ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

                        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.class);
                        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationARBroadcastReceiver.NOTIFICATION, holder.getNotification());
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(holder.itemView.getContext(), m, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) holder.itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

worked for me!